# Syntax error on blade view when using 2 variables

Tags: laravel

If I do this:

```php
@foreach($posts as $post)
  <x-post.block :post="$post" :displayThing="{{ json_encode(true) }}" />
@endforeach
```

I get `syntax error, unexpected token "<"` on the line of `<x-post`. However if I leave out the `:displayThing` (a variable used in `post.block`) then it works. Why is that?

Comment: `json_encode(true)` What exactly are you encoding here?

Comment: This is to pass a `true` value to the view